# How do I open this surface mounted kitchen light fixture?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, removal

Fluorescent light fixture--can't seem to get it open. It doesn't seem to want to unscrew at all, or squeeze in as if it had tabs that held it in. No visible screws on the metal either.

[image]

Comment: Did you try just turning the glass counterclockwise?

Comment: It's most likely a "squeeze to release", but requires more squeezing than you've been doing. Can you provide some close up pics of the plastic/metal interface (from a couple of different angles) so someone can give you a better guess.

Comment: Glass or plastic?

Comment: "Doesn't want to unscrew" <-- do you mean you can't turn the white part, or that you can rotate it but it doesn't drop down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that the entire fixture is supposed to rotate a little and unlock from a base plate, but someone was lazy when painting the ceiling last time and didn't remove the fixture first, they just painted around it and got paint in the joint. So now it is being prevented from turning by adhesion to the painted surface. I would run a razor blade /Exacto knife around the rim where it touches the ceiling paint to break that bond.

Comment: Excellent point! You may be on to something there.

Comment: This is exactly what it was, thank you! The -entire- assembly, nickel AND plastic, unscrewed from the back plate together and it was painted in place.